# Building a custom check box within a accordion

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox, accordion

I have a basic jQuery accordion and a custom build checkbox, the accordion works well, drops and retracts on-lick.

The problem is with my checkbox on its own I can check or unchecked via clicking on the check, however within my accordion it seems to be unclickable. Does anyone know why?

working fiddle here

*including working check box outside the accordion*

http://jsfiddle.net/edsilv/cgn4s8y7/#&togetherjs=R73iidT8Vq

```js
$(function() {
  var icons = {
    "header": "ui-icon-plusthick",
    "activeHeader": "ui-icon-minusthick"
  };
  
  $("#accordion").accordion({
    icons: icons,
    heightStyle: "content",
    active: false,
    collapsible: true,
  });
});
```

```css
.row-accord {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.row-accord span {
  line-height: 36px;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox] + .accord-text:before {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.42);
  display: block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  content: "";
  color: green;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + .accord-text:before {
  content: "\2713";
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: xx-large;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 2px solid green;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div id="accordion">
  <div class="row-accord">
    <label for=''>
      <input type='checkbox' class='singlecheck' checked/>
      <div class="accord-text"></div>
    </label>
    <span>
      title here
    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    hidden content here
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that setting the checkbox to hidden, prevents the click interaction from behaving as it normally would by default.

By adding a custom click handler, this is one way to get around the issue you are having.

For example (it's not perfect, but demonstrates a resolution):

```
$('input[type=checkbox] + .accord-text').click(function() {
    var isChecked = $(this).prev().prop('checked');
    $(this).prev().prop('checked', !isChecked);
});
```

Working fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/221mdv9p/

### Update

To reduce the area of the checkbox click zone, you can try adding the following style:

```
.accord-text { display: inline-block; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/221mdv9p/1/

### Update 2

You can also stop the click propagating to the outer containers, by using `evt.stopPropagation()`.  https://jsfiddle.net/221mdv9p/2/

Comment: is good, but I need only the checkbox checked if you click on the box, not the entire accordion. this will not work as i add lots of accordions as i need the user to be able to open without checking. thanks anyways

Comment: @BenjaminOats I've updated my answer.  Hopefully this works better now - it reduces the area taken up by the checkbox label zone.

Comment: wow, almost, but i need the checkbox not to effect the accordion dropdown. +1 for the infomation

Comment: @BenjaminOats Happy to help - please upvote if you found it useful :D